# Getting error while trying to retrieve lookupvalues from Sharepoint Online List in Powershell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

In the following code, I am getting an error

> Cannot convert the "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldLookupValue" value of type "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldLookupValue" to type "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldLookupValue".

I was following code I found on here to get lookup value.

```
$myContext = Get-PnPContext
$ELWeb = $myContext.Web
$siteReqListName = "ClassCreation"
$queryStr = 
    "<View>
        <Query>
            <Where>
                <Eq>
                    <FieldRef Name='Subsite_x0020_Created'/>
                    <Value Type='Integer'>0</Value>
                </Eq>
            </Where>
        </Query>

    </View>"
$sites = @()
$sites = Get-PnPListItem -List $siteReqListName -Query $queryStr -Web $ELWeb

Disconnect-PnPOnline
foreach ($site in $sites) {
    $itemId = $site["ID"]
    $siteTitle = $site["Title"]
    $lookup = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldLookupValue]$site["Class_x0020_Category"]
        $lookupValue=$lookup.LookupValue
```

}

Comment: In which line did you get this error ?`$lookup = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldLookupValue]$site["Class_x0020_Category"]`

Comment: check the type of `$site` by using $site["Class_x0020_Category"].GetType()

Comment: Hi ! yes, that line is what is giving the error. the field is a lookup field from another list in the same site. If i output the GetType() from that field, i see it is Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client.FieldLookupValue . . . so I would assume it would be oK ??